# How do you record the audio from a web flash video, e.g. from Hulu or YouTube, and make an audio podcast

Tags: sound, flash, streaming

I want to record the audio from flash videos on YouTube or Hulu to listen to later on my iPod or SanDisk mp3 player.

Is there any combination of tools that can accomplish this? Is it possible to record the audio in the background without having to listen to it while it's recording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to gather youtube audio. Which includes the usage of [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) and [Mobile Media Converter](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.htm).

For other video hosting services, you may also use Audacity to live record the audio.

Sorry, this is what I can say about this question, I don't know how to convert this to a podcast for sharing in the net, but for a later listening on iPod or SanDisk player, you can try dropping the audio files inside of it.

Good luck!